# Match.params.id don't show anything

Tags: parameters, match

```
import React, { useEffect} from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import { useDispatch, useSelector} from 'react-redux'
import { Row, Col, Image, ListGroup, Card, Button, ListGroupItem} from 'react-bootstrap'
import Rating from '../components/Rating'
import Message from '../components/Message'
import Loader from '../components/Loader'
import { listProductDetails } from '../actions/productActions'

const ProductScreen = ({ match }) => {
   const dispatch = useDispatch()
   const productDetails = useSelector(state => state.productDetails)
   const { loading, error, product} = productDetails


   useEffect(() => {
   dispatch(listProductDetails(match.params.id))
   }, [dispatch,match])
}
```

//Match.params.id throws an error and shows nothing. Do you have a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { useEffect} from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import { useDispatch, useSelector} from 'react-redux'
import { Row, Col, Image, ListGroup, Card, Button, ListGroupItem} from 
'react-bootstrap'
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import Rating from '../components/Rating'
import Message from '../components/Message'
import Loader from '../components/Loader'
import { listProductDetails } from '../actions/productActions'

const ProductScreen = ({ match }) => {
const dispatch = useDispatch()
const { id } = useParams();
const productDetails = useSelector(state => state.productDetails)
const { loading, error, product} = productDetails


useEffect(() => {
  dispatch(listProductDetails(id))//use id insted of match.params.id
 }, [dispatch,match])
}


return(
   <div className="ProductDetails">
     <div>
       <Carousel>
         {product.images &&
          product.images.map((item, i) => (
          <img
           className="CarouselImage"
           key={i}
           src={item.url}
           alt={`${i} Slide`}
           />
         ))}
       </Carousel>
      </div>
    </div>
);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).